# Boost Graphs. Equivalent technique to Inheritance

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I am pretty new to Boost Graphs and perhaps there is a solution to my problem.

I have a function that performs certain computation on a graph. It expects graphs with a particular properties, e.g. it expects that all edges will have a numerical weight value and all vertices will have a numerical field (lets call it a color, it will be preset to some meaningful value prior to call to my function).

Imagine that I have a set of different graph types, all of them have numeric weight property on a link and all their vertices have a numeric color, however they also have other properties for vertices and edges. **My question is** how can I use my function for all of these graph types?

1. Naturally to me it seems like an inheritance, if boost graphs would be classes then my function could operate on a base classes, and I could pass in pointer to a child classes etc.
2. Initially I've been trying to declare my function to take in a template graph argument, but soon I realized that it doesn't work (or I couldn't figure out how to do it properly).

Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what property map's were invented for in BGL, I recommend spending more time on the doc (it can be quite confusing). (option 2 btw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "technique equivalent to inheritance" is called "polymorphism" and BGL favours "static polymorphism" (option 2!).

This is the *pay-for-what-you-need* approach to generic libraries.

You *can* adapt any type (hierarchy) for use with BGL's static polymorphism though:

- [How to <strike>Convert</strike> Adapt Existing Graphs to BGL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/graph/doc/leda_conversion.html)

Also use property maps to link the properties (weight, color) to the vertices/edges.

- [map set/get requests into C++ class/structure changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863061/map-set-get-requests-into-c-class-structure-changes/27863767#27863767)