# Boost BGL Transitive reduction

Tags: c++, boost, graph-theory, boost-graph, transitive-closure

I try to use the transitive_reduction of boost, but I don't know how to use it.

I have a graph defined with :

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, IQsNode*> Graph;
typedef Graph::vertex_descriptor Vertex;
```

I would like to call the method :

```
Graph TC;
boost::transitive_reduction(_fullGraph, TC,g_to_tr_map_stor,g_to_tc_map_stor);
```

I don't know the type I must use for "g_to_tr_map_stor" and "g_to_tc_map_stor".

According with information i readed , it must be a map from vertices
to integers. I try many kind of map but without success.

Some ideas ?

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as my documentation tells me this is not public API. This implies that you can find the place where it's being used internally and use that as an example of how to use it.

Interestingly, this is not the case. This might lead one to think that the documentation is lagging/forgotten

> **CAVEAT** Using undocumented API surface risks breaking your code on upgrade, without notice.

Here's the simplest thing I could think of to satisfy the interface:

```
Graph const g = make_random();

Graph tr;
std::map<Graph::vertex_descriptor, Graph::vertex_descriptor> g_to_tr;
std::vector<size_t> id_map(num_vertices(g));
std::iota(id_map.begin(), id_map.end(), 0u);

transitive_reduction(g, tr, make_assoc_property_map(g_to_tr), id_map.data());
```

So, it uses a `std::map` to pass as the `g_to_tr` vertex association map. And we pass and vertex id-map that is just increasing ids for each vertex.

- See [map set/get requests into C++ class/structure changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863061/map-set-get-requests-into-c-class-structure-changes/27863767#27863767) for more background on property maps

If you  print the results:

```
print_graph(g);
std::cout << "----------------------------\n";
for (auto& e : g_to_tr)
    std::cout << "Mapped " << e.first << " to " << e.second << "\n";
std::cout << "----------------------------\n";
print_graph(tr);
```

You may get an idea of what it does.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75de2df6ea63906b)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/transitive_reduction.hpp>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp> // dumping graphs
#include <boost/graph/graphviz.hpp>      // generating pictures

using namespace boost;

struct IQsNode { };
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::bidirectionalS, IQsNode*> Graph;

Graph make_random();

int main() {
    Graph const g = make_random();

    Graph tr;
    std::map<Graph::vertex_descriptor, Graph::vertex_descriptor> g_to_tr;
    std::vector<size_t> id_map(num_vertices(g));
    std::iota(id_map.begin(), id_map.end(), 0u);

    transitive_reduction(g, tr, make_assoc_property_map(g_to_tr), id_map.data());

    print_graph(g);
    std::cout << "----------------------------\n";
    for (auto& e : g_to_tr)
        std::cout << "Mapped " << e.first << " to " << e.second << "\n";
    std::cout << "----------------------------\n";
    print_graph(tr);

    // generating graphviz files
    { std::ofstream dot("g.dot");  write_graphviz(dot, g); }
    { std::ofstream dot("tr.dot"); write_graphviz(dot, tr); }
}

// generating test data
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>
#include <random>
Graph make_random() {
    Graph g;
    std::mt19937 prng (std::random_device{}());
    generate_random_graph(g, 10, 5, prng);

    return g;
}
```

Here is the [Wikipedia sample] reproduced:

```
Graph make_wikipedia() {
    Graph g;
    enum {a,b,c,d,e};
    add_edge(a,b,g);
    add_edge(a,c,g);
    add_edge(a,d,g);
    add_edge(a,e,g);
    add_edge(b,d,g);
    add_edge(c,d,g);
    add_edge(c,e,g);
    add_edge(d,e,g);
    return g;
}
```

[image]

Here's an animation of 4 of the randomly generated graphs and their *transitive reductions*:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you for your complete answer. It work but in the main graph I have a pointer to a class "IQsNode*" and in the result graph TC, the pointer is not valid "0xcdcdcdcd". Do I have to set manually after or is there a way to tell boost to fill it automatically ?

Comment: You can use the mappings to transfer it, e.g. [**live:** `for (auto& e : g_to_tr) tr[e.second] = g[e.first];`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c177fcd39b464afb) (memory leaks are by design there :))