# Efficient Transitive Reduction of Adjacency List DAG

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, adjacency-list, graph-reduction

I have a large directed acyclic graph, and I'd like to compute the transitive reduction of that graph.

I'm currently computing the transitive reduction using a naive depth-first search, but that algorithm is too slow for my use case. However, the efficient algorithms I've been able to find work on an adjacency *matrix* representation, whereas my representation is roughly equivalent to an adjacency *list*. (It's actually represented as a set of C++ objects, each with pointers to their children and parents).

I obviously could transform my DAG into an adjacency matrix, do the reduction, and transform it back; but that seems a bit wasteful, and I'd like a simpler algorithm if possible.

My graph contains ~100,000 nodes.

Comment: I'm removing the C++ tag as right now this is about an algorithm, not actual code.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the names of graph algorithms, but it looks like [`boost::transitive_closure`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/graph/doc/transitive_closure.html) from [Boost Graph](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/graph/doc/table_of_contents.html)

Comment: Transitive closure is actually the opposite of a transitive reduction. Computing the closure means "if there exists an indirect path from A to B, add a direct path" whereas a transitive reduction means "remove all edges that can be removed without actually changing the DAG." (So, if you have edges A->B, B->C, and A->C, you can remove the A->C edge, since it's implied by A->B and B->C).

Comment: @IanPudney There's an undocumented [`boost::transitive_reduction`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/boost/graph/transitive_reduction.hpp): https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200511/1896169