# Altering Boost Topological Sort

Tags: c++, boost, boost-graph

I'm trying to adapt [this](https://github.com/jafingerhut/cljol/blob/master/doc/transitive-reduction-notes.md#constructing-sorted-lists-of-edges-during-topological-sorting) git page on simultaneously obtaining a topologically sorted list of incoming vertices whilst topologically sorting. The reason I'm doing this is to compare [this](https://github.com/jafingerhut/cljol/blob/master/doc/transitive-reduction-notes.md#computing-the-transitive-reduction-of-a-dag) implementation of transitive reduction with boost's [undocumented version](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/graph/transitive_reduction.hpp).

I'm trying to edit boost's own [topological sort](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/boost/graph/topological_sort.hpp). From what I can tell, all I need to do is to override the discover_vertex or examine_edge functions to append a value to specific vectors depending on the vertex but I'm struggling to do so.

Should I pass in a data structure to the visitor or another OutputIterator? How can I properly override these functions and update either of these two options?

If anybody could shed some light that would be lovely. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help if you shared some actual code that you have trouble with. Or at least the expected output datastructure/example data. Meanwhile all I can say is that you need not modify boost's code to override the visitor events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was slightly wrong in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77534818/altering-boost-topological-sort#comment136697413_77534818). I remembered `topological_sort` as having a more general-purpose interface.

So, let me show you how I'd replicate topological-sort directly against the `depth_first_search` interface, which will will make it easy for you to modify the behavior to your taste.

```
template <typename G> auto my_algo(G const& g) {
    using V   = G::vertex_descriptor;
    using E   = G::edge_descriptor;
    using Out = std::deque<V>;

    struct Visitor : public boost::dfs_visitor<> {
        Out& o;
        Visitor(Out& o) : o(o) {}
        void back_edge(E, G const&) const { throw std::runtime_error("cycle"); }
        void finish_vertex(V u, G const&) const { o.push_front(u); }
    };

    Out order;
    depth_first_search(g, boost::visitor(Visitor{order}));

    return order;
}
```

At this point it does nothing more than just the original `topological_sort`. Indeed we can verify using [the documentation example](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_83_0/libs/graph/doc/topological_sort.html#:%7E:text=The%20output%20is):

```
boost::adjacency_list<> g;
add_edge(0, 1, g);
add_edge(2, 4, g);
add_edge(2, 5, g);
add_edge(0, 3, g);
add_edge(1, 4, g);
add_edge(4, 3, g);

fmt::print("Order: {}\n", my_algo(g));
```

Which prints the expected: **[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1824b7a4597ae8d2)**

```
Order: [2, 5, 0, 1, 4, 3]
```

Comment: Perhaps using this example you can illustrate the expected outcome. If you do I'm happy to show how I'd implement the extra functionality

Comment: (I'm assuming you've seen https://stackoverflow.com/a/29200511/85371, but in case you didn't, it may help you)