# Using Boost Property Maps with Bundled Types

Tags: c++, templates, boost-graph

I am having issues getting the property map for the graph I am making. I am using bundled properties. I have stripped it down to the example below. I receive an error when I try to grab the type for `IndexMap`. The error from both a VC++ compiler and gcc is something along the lines of `error forming a reference to void or illegal use of type void`. The error is inside of boost's `adjacency_list.hpp`, but is caused by my instantiation of `boost::property_map`. I have been unable to understand what the correct type should be. I read the boost docs on [bundled properties](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/graph/doc/bundles.html), but found them a little unhelpful. Any thoughts?

Edit: I am using boost 1.67.0.

Edit2: Apparently changing to `vecS` instead of `listS` for the vertex representation fixes this. However, I would prefer to use `listS` since I need to modify the graph while iterating over it.

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_traits.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/properties.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct MyVertex
{
    std::string m_name;
};

int main()
{
    using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, MyVertex>;
    using Vertex = boost::graph_traits<graph_t>::vertex_descriptor;
    using IndexMap = boost::property_map<graph_t, boost::vertex_index_t>::type;
    std::unique_ptr<graph_t> graph;
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> edges{ {0,1}, {0,2}, {1,2}, {3,4}, {1,3}, {1,4}};
    graph = std::make_unique<graph_t>(edges.begin(), edges.end(), 5);
    IndexMap index = boost::get(boost::vertex_index, *graph);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I explained [earlier today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51138794/how-to-use-boost-make-label-writer-to-write-edge-properties#comment89290926_51141906) your graph does not have a vertex index. If you want it to have one, you must add it yourself.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/51b2d91e6db86398)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

struct MyVertex {
    int id;
    std::string name;
};

using graph_t = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::listS, boost::undirectedS, MyVertex>;
using Vertex = graph_t::vertex_descriptor;

int main() {
    graph_t g;
    auto v0 = add_vertex(MyVertex{0, "zero"},  g);
    auto v1 = add_vertex(MyVertex{1, "one"},   g);
    auto v2 = add_vertex(MyVertex{2, "two"},   g);
    auto v3 = add_vertex(MyVertex{3, "three"}, g);
    auto v4 = add_vertex(MyVertex{4, "four"},  g);

    for (auto [from, to] : { std::pair { v0, v1 }, { v0, v2 }, { v1, v2 }, { v3, v4 }, { v1, v3 }, { v1, v4 } }) {
        add_edge(from, to, g);
    }
}
```

Now you can use the id as the vertex index:

```
auto index = get(&MyVertex::id, g);
```

---

PS. In C++11 write

```
for (auto p : std::vector<std::pair<Vertex, Vertex> > { { v0, v1 }, { v0, v2 }, { v1, v2 }, { v3, v4 }, { v1, v3 }, { v1, v4 } }) {
    add_edge(p.first, p.second, g);
}
```

In C++03 write: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c08ca797d8ccec09)</kbd>**